# Visual Studio Profiling: Start/Stop from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

Is there a possibility to start/stop the visual studio (Professional 2012+) profiler from code? I know you can start it paused, but to start the profiling, you have to click on a button in the visual studio.

In my case, I would like to start it when clicking on a button in my application, which switches to a new view, and automatically stop it when the UI was loaded. I would like to see why there is such a large delay until the UI shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not used it before, but it seems you're looking for [Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.profiler.aspx).

[DataCollection.StartProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.profiler.datacollection.startprofile.aspx) and [DataCollection.StopProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.profiler.datacollection.stopprofile.aspx) looks like the methods you're interested in.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thanks

Comment: If you need guidance about where to get the `DataCollection` type and how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514149.aspx

Comment: "Your build must reference the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll library, located in the Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Team Tools\Performance Tools directory."